# Wordpress Exclude Data From Category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide the date and time from specific categorys on wordress. I have the code below which is what every page displays and automatically applied to every category. How can i exclude certain categorys from showing this information.

Thanks in advance

```
if (have_posts()):

while(have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
  <div align="center" class="blogimage">  <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_single' ); ?>
   <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_date(); ?>  
       <p> By </p>
         <?php the_author();?>
         </div>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (have_posts()):

while(have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
  <div align="center" class="blogimage">  <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'shop_single' ); ?>
   <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php if(!in_category(10)):?>
         <?php the_date(); ?>  
       <?php endif;?>
       <p> By </p>
         <?php the_author();?>
         </div>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

`!in_category(10)` 10 is category id. [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/)

Comment: Many thanks Torv you are a legend! Been looking high and low for an answer to this.

Comment: apparntly !in_category will only let you select a single category, is there anyway i can exclude multiple?

Comment: In [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) `in_category( int|string|array $category, int|object $post = null )` So you can use arrays for multiple categories.